# Returning mutable vs. returning immutable (non-member-)objects

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmutablearray

I hardly ever see the second one used and I wonder why?

- Neither would it **break support** for situations where an `NSArray` is expected (as it's a subclass).
- Nor would it **break encapsulation** by revealing mutable internals.

Under the precondition that it's never a mutable ivar that's returned, <sup>*(which should be common sense anyway)*</sup>
I can right now only think of advantages of using the second.

- It actually **is** mutable. And muting is **safe** here, so **why prevent it**?
- No need to call `[[[foo fooBar] mutableCopy] autorelease]`, which **needlessly allocates additional memory** and **needlessly wastes time**.

Here are the method variations:

```
- (NSArray *)fooBar {
    NSMutableArray *fooArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    //populate fooArray
    return fooArray;
}

- (NSMutableArray *)fooBar {
    NSMutableArray *fooArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    //populate fooArray
    return fooArray;
}
```

I'm asking as **my project has a bunch of methods with the same pattern**.
And in **most** of the times the **returned array will be modified afterwards** (merged, edited, etc).
So I think it **should be totally fine** to return `NSMutableArrays`, yet **nobody seems to be doing it**.

`NSMutableArray`, `NSMutableSet`, `NSMutableDictionary`… it's basically the same deal.

Comment: Easy with the bold there. Bolding quickly goes from helpful to noise; a little bold goes a long way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose the first variation was preferred because polymorphism was preferred.

In either case, both methods return an instance of `NSMutableArray`, the only difference being that the first one hides that fact from the caller. In other words, the first variation is *not* safer than the second. It's essentially using polymorphism to tell the caller that any type of `NSArray` might be returned. If you need that kind of flexibility in your code, it definitely has it's advantages. (e.g., if one day, for whatever reason, you need to return a custom `NSArray` subclass, your code won't break at that level).

However, you seem to prefer communicating intent to the caller - i.e. that you actually return mutable arrays - which is also OK. To make everyone happy (if there is such thing anyways...), I suggest renaming the 2nd method to:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)mutableFooBar {
    NSMutableArray *fooArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    //populate fooArray
    return fooArray;
}
```

As a side note, I think that the following is a slightly more efficient way to convert an existing immutable array into a mutable one:

```
NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:fooArray];
```

(correct me if I'm wrong on that assumption).

I hope this answers your question...

Comment: There already are 19 methods returning `NSSets` in one class alone (or rather a protocol and its implementations). And 5 in another protocol/class. And 7 in another. Doubling those methods would make my project a nightmare to maintenance. The methods are set up to be highly granular/modular. And their results are—as stated in my question—often unioned/subtracted/intersected. There's no chance of any of them ever returning an NSSet that happens to be an ivar. Instead they return sets of objects that were collated on demand and during method runtime. 90% of them internally use NSMutableSet.

Comment: Forgot to mention that the initial reason for my question is that performance & memory is crucial. (see my more detailed comment on David V's answer as well)

Answer (score 4):

For an explanation of using mutable versus immutable, check out Apple's documentation on [Object Mutability](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html).

In general, it is best to return an immutable version, unless it is specifically your intent that the object returned always be an immutable object available for any client to change. You should create your interfaces based on the intent of the interface, not off the current implementation. It is possible that requirements will change and you will need to change the implementation of fooBar such that it does return an instance variable. By returning mutable arrays you ensure that you encapsulate not only your instance variables, but your current implementation.

So, you may have a valid place to return a mutable array (I don't know), but you see most code passing immutable arrays because it fully encapsulates their variables and their implementations.

Comment: While both of your answers totally make sense, I'm still not sure if my situation might not be a rare case where using NSMutableSet might be appropriate. I wouldn't have bothered about having to create additional mutable copies of (my already mutable, yet disclosed) NSSets if performance & memory weren't such a rather big deal for this project. The scenarios in which my project could be used can potentially have dozens of thousands (or even much more) of objects in those sets. Cloning those takes additional time and memory. (See my comment on octy's answer as well)

Comment: Yours may be one of the cases where it is appropriate - I don't know. As long as you recognize that by exposing the mutable you are forcing any implementations to work in such a way that mutable is acceptable, and accept that you can go ahead and make it mutable.

Answer (score 0):

Having a method return a mutable instance like that looks suspicious.

As the caller you have to question the original method signature and wonder if it really is safe to mutate the returned value. After all the class may inadvertently be returning a pointer to internal state.

If profiling reveals that this copy is indeed expensive, I usually change the method signature to make it obvious that the mutability is intended. Perhaps with something like:

```
- (void)populateFooBars:(NSMutableArray *)array;
```

That way it is clear that the mutability of the result is intentional.

Comment: I have excessively documented my code (and would do so for those mutable return values in particular). None of my classes' methods return (or will ever return) any NSMutableSet representing internal state. This is an internal framework convention, if you will. The methods in question mostly return collated Core Data relationships. One class alone has 19 of those methods. Additionally having 19 methods beginning with `-(void)populate…` would make reading the code rather difficult. Also it would require me to add at least one line per call for the array pointer. (see comments on other answers)